# How to allow "cyrillic" characters in new Media Gallery (description for images, tags)

Tags: image, magento2.4.4, wysiwyg, media, tags

Just today I found out that Magento 2.4.4 have a new "Media Gallery" allowing to add a description (alt text) for images and tags.I want to benefit from it to add "alt text" to images I use as banners (due "page builder" doesn't have such functionality for banners, but only for regular images).

Unfortunately, i found out "Cyrillic" characters are not allowed. It seems like it only allows using "Latin" alphabet and numbers and some symbols.
[image]

Is there any possibility to change that rule and allow it to use Cyrillic?